# Working with Java.io.file, when ever I try to read a cert from it it always points to wrong path

Tags: java, resources, keystore, java-io, jsse

I am trying to read a cert with file IO , every time I try accessing my cert under

```
testApp/src/main/resources -> cert
```

it always reads

```
X:\workspace1\testApp\target\classes\cert\test.p12
```

And here is my code that I am using, It always exceptions out with null pointer.

```
// String fileName = "config/sample.txt";
    ClassLoader classLoader = App2.class.getClassLoader();

    File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("cert/test.p12").getFile());
    FileInputStream fm = new FileInputStream(file);
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    try {
        ks.load(fm, "test".toCharArray());
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Key key = ks.getKey("test", "test".toCharArray());
    Certificate cert = ks.getCertificate("test");
    PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();
    System.out.println("Public key");
    System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(publicKey.getEncoded()));
    fm.close();
```

I want to read this cert to extract public or private key.

Comment: Resources are not files. Use `getResourceAsStream()` amd cut out all the `File*` classes.

Comment: NB You need to close the input stream after use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me

```
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("./cert/test.p12").getFile());
```

Comment: `classLoader.getResourceAsStream("./cert/test.p12")` would have worked even better, without the assumption that it is a file, or `File`, at all.